# "Error: /ioerror in --filter--" in converting PDF to print supported format with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, printers, hp-ux

I am gonna convert PDF files with Ghostscript in HP-UX system so I can print those files in LX and LQ printers. For LX printers --for example, I use this command:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -r120x216 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=eps9high -sPAPERSIZE=letter -sOutputFile=TEST.TEMP.pdf.LXPRINT TEST.pdf
```

Every PDF files work just fine. But everytime I convert PDF files that contain images, it gives me error as follow:

```
Error: /ioerror in --filter--
Operand stack:
   --dict:6/15(L)--   false   --dict:9/17(L)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   2   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   3187   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   1749   6   13   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1151/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:288/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:21/40(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:7/15(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GNU Ghostscript 0.08.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

As you can see, I used Ghostscript 8.71.1 and my system is HP-UX Itanium v11.23.

I have been installed all the dependencies --jpeg, libXrender and everything-- but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the binaries from? Maybe the packager didn't enable image rendering (or manually disabled it), and maybe he compiled a statically linked binary?

Is it possible for you to compile it yourself from the sources?

If you compile yourself, you may need to edit some of the makefiles in order to enable image rendering. Watch out for thes *.dev keywords in the makefiles. Some ar commented out by default.

***Edit:***  Are your PDFs in any way special? Did you cross-test if Ghostscript 8.71 on a different OS platform (say, Linux or Windows) can handle your PDFs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the binaries from http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/PostScript/ghostscript-8.71.1/. How do I know whether this binaries enabled image rendering or not? Can you suggest which part of makefiles to enable image rendering.

Comment: The link you provided seems to suggest that JPEG and PNG support are indeed compiled into your Ghostscript HPUX-binaries. But there they also say you additionally need `libpng`, `tiff` and `jpeg` installed on your HPUX system **at runtime** for this to work. You seem meet this condition...

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance you are still having issues.
I had exactly the same issue, eventually tracked it down to a very small /tmp mount

testing with

```
mount -o bind /path/to/space/ /tmp
```

led to the above issue going away, and after playing a bit further found that

```
export TMPDIR="/path/to/space/";
```

also worked

I'm working with Debian Lenny, and ImageMagick 6.3.7
I also considered

[How do I change temp path of imagemagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204060/how-do-i-change-temp-path-of-imagemagick)

but it didn't work for me, and I didn't want to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with tmp folder and  the file that imagemagic creates there. imagic-{some hash characters} i add the " -limit memory 512" to limit the memory consumption and deleted the temporary file. That fixed the issue.