# How do I change temp path of imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to change the temporary path of imagemagick from a path in C: to a path on E:

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean temporary image's path? What does variable `MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH` looks like?

See: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Comment: @f01 Should the server be restarted? Should the environment variables be modified at the installation time? http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/imagemagick/www/advanced-windows-installation.html I'm out of ideas...